# python ipopt install error

Tags: python, terminal, ipopt

I am trying to install ipopt from mac terminal, but I got the following error:
[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM0g7.png)

> /usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch
>   x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/src/callback.o
>   build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/src/pyipoptcoremodule.o
>   -L/usr/local/lib -lipopt -lcoinblas -lcoinmumps -lcoinmetis -lcoinlapack -ldl -lm -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/pyipopt/pyipoptcore.cpython-36m-darwin.so
>
> ld:
>   library not found for -lipopt
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)
>   error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

Comment: It seems missing ipopt library, can you post the info of `brew search ipopt`?

Answer (score 0):

`ipopt` library is missing. Try

- `brew install homebrew/science/ipopt`
- or https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt/wiki/Ipopt_on_Mac_OS_X

then run `pip install ipopt` again.

Comment: I got the following errors instead:

 src/cyipopt.c:239:10: fatal error: 'IpStdCInterface.h' file not found
    #include "IpStdCInterface.h"

Comment: @Raindraconis1758 is it during the process of `pip install pyipopt`? What command are you using?

Comment: @Raindraconis1758 try follow the instructions here https://github.com/xuy/pyipopt#install

Comment: i've been trying to follow this link from the beginning but somehow im not getting any progress. I used 'pip3 install ipopt'

Comment: following github's instruction, I got 'ld: library not found for -lcoinblas' (which I indeed do not have)

Comment: did u install ipopt from the source? sorry I dont have a osx env. Can't verify the solution.

Comment: https://projects.coin-or.org/BuildTools/wiki/user-compile#CompilingandInstallingthePackage

Comment: installation was unsuccessful, errors always occur when I command 'python setup.py build'

Comment: It says to change the directory to where pyipopt was installed, but whenever i changed the directory it showed me couldn't find lib, and when I keep the directory as it is, it runs fine all the way up to coinblas

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if it's too late, but you can try here

```
git clone https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt
make
make test
make install
```

that includes the missing files `Ipopt/src/Interfaces/IpIpStdCInterface.h` that you mentioned before